# in Android, unable to inflate Google Maps v2 fragment for SDK version 8

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

It used to work, then I think it broke when I updated Eclipse to API 19. Now when I try to run my Maps Activity, I get the error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)` So I started over trying to recreate my Maps Activity using the tutorials found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html). So now I'm back to just getting the map to display. Here's what I've got in the layout:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_wcbc_FRAG"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and here's the Activity:

```
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WCBCMap extends FragmentActivity {

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;
Button back_BTN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wcbc_map);
    back_BTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backMap_wcbc_btn);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_wcbc_FRAG);
    myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

    // --- back button
    back_BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent plI = new Intent(
                    "com....BUTTON_INTERFACE");
            startActivity(plI);
            finish();

        }
    });
    // --- end back button

}// --- END onCreate

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
        String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(getApplicationContext ());
        AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                WCBCMap.this);
        LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
        LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
        LicenseDialog.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

}

}
```

and here's the Manifest relevant info:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.wcbc.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.wcbc.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

.... <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my API Key is here" />
</application>
```

I'm targeting Android 4.22, I don't need to target Google APIs 4.22 do I? And I have the Google Play Services and Support v4 libraries in there. So can anyone see why the map won't inflate?

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of the Google Play Services library, including maps v2, drops support for API Level 8 (Froyo).  It is now Gingerbread+.

You can either use an older version of the play services library, or drop support for Froyo in your own app.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html

Comment: Jon, I see what you mean. So I kicked my project up to API 10, as high as my Android 2.3.4 phone can go and it's still giving me the error where it can't inflate the fragment. Now that I'm at API 10, do I not use FragmentActivity and SupportMapFragment in the XML?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting.  I actually never use fragments from xml.  I always add them with the FragmentManager.  But you do still need to use FragmentActivity and SupportMapFragment.

Comment: ok, I got the Map to work. Thanks to Jon for letting me know that as of Oct. 31, 2013 Google Maps aren't supported on API 8. I bumped the project up to API 10, but I still struggled to get it to work. The solution I found is that now in the SDK Manager, under Extras, there's Google Play Services for Froyo - you have to install that. Then import that library project into your project. ie. import --> google_play_services_froyo --> libproject --> google-play-services_lib. I don't know WHY it works since I'm on API 10, but it does.

Comment: Interesting. You might want to report that as a bug to Google. I would imagine that API level 10 should be supported without the Froyo specific jar.